# Stock Market API - Top Gainers/Losers

Tags: api, stocks

I'm looking for a free API which I can use to retrieve the stock market's top gainers and top losers for the current day. I've checked out Google and Yahoo's API's and they don't seem to do this. I can get price quotes on specific stocks, but nothing about top gainers or losers. Does anyone know of an API that does this?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a web API.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?
https://www.alphavantage.co does seem to have good API's but not sure if they have the exact one you are looking for (I am looking for the same thing too)

Answer (score 2):

Use Google's Finance API. 
This URL gets the stock information for the end day results of a market between two given dates. Check every market and compare the data appropriately.

```
http://finance.google.co.uk/finance/historical?q=LON:VOD&startdate=Mar+14+2013&enddate=Mar+15+2013&output=csv
```

Comment: Google Finance API has been deprecated.

Comment: In the stock market, "top gainers and losers" means "tell me what stocks gained the most and what stocks lost the most." Data on a market as a whole is probably not what the original asker wanted. (I initially voted this down, but I think your interpretation was reasonable if you haven't spent a lot of time talking to traders, so I undid my downvote.)